# Errors while dredging a pre-setup glmmTMB using fitTMB() in R

Tags: r, statistics, modeling

I'm using a specifically designed `glmmTMB` to run a weighted binomial model with random effects. The `dredge()` function from `MuMIn` is normally compatible with `glmmTMB` but I am receiving an error.

Reproducible example using the `iris` dataset. Note the models show convergence warnings due to being randomly generated but still run. My own model is set up the exact same way and does converge when run like so.

```
library(TMB)
library(glmmTMB)
library(MuMIn)
library(tidyverse)

#Set up the data to fit a negative binomial model
data(iris)
df <- iris %>%
  mutate(used=rep(c(0,1),times=75)) #random binomial response variable


# Create the model according to Muff et al. (2020)
## Link: https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/204737/fisher_rsf_and_ssf.html?sequence=27&isAllowed=y
df$weights <- ifelse(df$used == 1, 1, 1000)

# Set up the model, but do not yet fit it
TMBStruc.ex <- glmmTMB(used~
                      Sepal.Length +
                      Sepal.Width +
                      Petal.Length +
                      Petal.Width +
                      (1|Species) +
                      (0+Sepal.Length|Species) +
                      (0+Sepal.Width|Species) +
                      (0+Petal.Length|Species) +
                      (0+Petal.Width|Species),
                    data=df, family=binomial, weight=weights, doFit=FALSE)

# Fix the standard deviation of the first random term, which is the (1|id) component 
# in the above model equation
TMBStruc.ex$parameters$theta[1] = log(1e3)

# Tell glmmTMB not to change the first entry of the vector of variances, 
# and give all other variances another indicator to make sure they can be freely estimated
TMBStruc.ex$mapArg = list(theta=factor(c(NA,1:4))) #The 1:X value has to be the number of fixed terms  

m <- glmmTMB:::fitTMB(TMBStruc.ex) #This is successful
summary(m)

dredge(m) #Not successful 

#I get the following error:
## Error in seq_len(ncols) :
##   argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
## In addition: Warning messages:
##   1: In while (CLASS == "list") { :
##       the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
##   2: In seq_len(ncols) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

I've tried running the `dredge` directly with success (shown below), so it has to do with the way I've set it up.

```
TMBStruc.ex2 <- glmmTMB(used~
                         Sepal.Length +
                         Sepal.Width +
                         Petal.Length +
                         Petal.Width +
                         (1|Species) +
                         (0+Sepal.Length|Species) +
                         (0+Sepal.Width|Species) +
                         (0+Petal.Length|Species) +
                         (0+Petal.Width|Species),
                       data=df, family=binomial, weight=weights) #This is successful
dredge(TMBStruc.ex2) #This is successful
```

Is there a way to resolve the errors I've found and run the dredge with all the presets and arguments intact?

Comment: Another good reason not to dredge :-)

Comment: I haven't looked at this carefully yet, but recent versions of glmmTMB (at least the development version, I don't remember if it's in the CRAN version yet or not) allow you to specify a `map` argument to fix some values (and the `start` argument to specify their fixed values); doing it that way might get you around any problems you're having with hacking it via fitTMB

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker. I'll look into it. My current plan is to see if I can get around dredging but I might circle back to this. Beyond the current issue, I've realized that the 4 in `TMBStruc.ex$mapArg = list(theta=factor(c(NA,1:4)))` has to change based on the number of parameters the model is currently running, making things even tougher.

Comment: Yes, varying length of `theta` would definitely be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine if we pass `start` and `map` directly to `glmmTMB` (as is possible since version 1.0.0 of `glmmTMB`):

```r
m <- glmmTMB(used~
                      Sepal.Length +
                      Sepal.Width +
                      Petal.Length +
                      Petal.Width +
                      (1|Species) +
                      (0+Sepal.Length|Species) +
                      (0+Sepal.Width|Species) +
                      (0+Petal.Length|Species) +
                      (0+Petal.Width|Species),
                      data=df,
                      family=binomial,
                      weight=weights,
                      start = list(theta=c(log(1e3), rep(0,4))),
                      map = list(theta=factor(c(NA, 1:4)))
                      )

summary(m)
dredge(m)
```